# .Trim() when string is empty or null

Tags: c#

I'm receiving some data from the client in the form of json.
I'm writing this:

```
string TheText; // or whould it be better string TheText = ""; ?
TheText = ((serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["TheText"])).Trim());
```

If the variable that's being parsed from json comes back empty, does this code crash when I call the .Trim() method?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it'll crash if it's null...

Comment: (myValue ?? "").Trim() will allways work.

Comment: With C# 6.0 we can now use null-conditional operators, like theText?.Trim()

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the serializer returns an empty string, `Trim` will do nothing.

If the serializer returns `null`, you will get a `NullReferenceException` on the call to `Trim`.

Your code would be better written (as far as initialization is concerned) like this:

```
string theText = 
            ((serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["TheText"])).Trim());
```

There is no point in declaring and initializing the variable and the immediately assigning to it.

The following would be safest, if you don't know what the serializer might return:

```
string theText = ((serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["TheText"])));

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(theText))
{
    theText = theText.Trim();
}
```

Comment: If you've got to trim loads of fields though, this is a pain, is there no way of extending the trim method to not bother if the string is null?

Comment: @SelectDistinct - you can always write an extension method that does exactly that.

Comment: @Oded Yeah was being lazy, posted for reference for anyone else

Answer (score 42):

You can use elvis operator, also known as "null-conditional-operators":

```
GetNullableString()?.Trim(); // returns NULL or trimmed string
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator for those unaware of the meaning of Elvis ?:

Comment: This is actually called the "safe navigation operator". 
The Elvis operator is ?:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator

Comment: In C# it's called a null-conditional operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: nobody cares how it's called, if it works, it works <3

Answer (score 17):

Calling `Trim()` on an empty string will result in an empty string. Calling `Trim()` on `null` will throw `NullReferenceException`

Comment: What's the cleanest way to check for `string.IsNullOrEmptyOrBlank`?

Comment: @CodeBlend: What do you mean by blank?

Comment: Aha - [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

Answer (score 17):

Some basic techniques to check strings against `null` before you trim:

- `(mystring ?? "").Trim()`
  The "null coalescing operator" `??` will return the first operand. Only when this operand is null, the second operand will be returned (as a kind of default value).
  The above example will return an **empty string** if mystring is null.
- `mystring?.Trim()`
  The "null conditional operator" `?` will short cirtuit a chain of operations in dot-notation. If the operand is null, the following operations will not be executed and null will be returned.
  The above example will return **null** if mystring is null.
- `if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mystring) ) { ... }`
  the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method may replace trimming if you actually want to check if there is real content in mystring. It returns true if the operand is null, empty, or nothing but whitespace characters.

Answer (score 16):

If you have a few fields you wish to trim but your getting exceptions for those records that have nulls in certain fields, then writing a quick extension method will be the easiest method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string TrimIfNotNull(this string value)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                return value.Trim();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Sample example of use:

```
string concatenated = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", myObject.fieldOne.TrimIfNotNull(), myObject.fieldTwo.TrimIfNotNull(), myObject.fieldThree.TrimIfNotNull());
```

Answer (score 6):

- No, it would *not* be better to initialize `TheText` to `""`. You're assigning to it right afterwards.
- No, it won't crash – `Trim()` works just fine on an empty string. If by "empty" you mean that it can be null, then yes, it will crash; you could have null remain null with a null-conditional call:

  ```
  string TheText =
      serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["TheText"])?.Trim();
  ```

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in some of the comments, you may now use c# 6 Null-conditional operators with this syntax:

```
string TheText = (serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["TheText"]))?.Trim();
```

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had to check a string if it is null, empty or whitespace using just one if condition and for that I found out that you can add "" to a null string to make it non null.

```
string test = GetStringFromSomeWhere(); // null
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(test.Trim())) { return true; } // Exception
```

So I did this instead

```
string test = GetStringFromSomeWhere() + ""; // ""
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(test.Trim())) { return true; } // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as beblow

```
 string theText = (((serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["TheText"])))+ string.Empty).Trim();
```